# how to send data as well as child component to a component - JavaScript - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-props, react-state

```
render() {
    return(
        <Scroll>
            <MessageList
                questions={this.state.questions}
                answers={this.state.answers}
            />
        </Scroll>
    )
}
```

the above code is working, I am wrapping MessageList component by Scroll component, questions and and answers will be received by MessageList component as props. Good!

Now, if I also want to send data to the Scroll component, for example:

```
render() {
    return(
        <Scroll>
            endTime={this.state.endTime}
            <MessageList
                questions={this.state.questions}
                answers={this.state.answers}
            />
        </Scroll>
    )
}
```

notice that I'm trying to pass endTime to Scroll component and it's not working. How to solve this issue?

Comment: You can pass it as props and use it like this.props.endTime.
Or if you want to use it the way you have written you have to get it from children props.

render() {
    return(
        <Scroll endTime={this.state.endTime}>
            <MessageList
                questions={this.state.questions}
                answers={this.state.answers}
            />
        </Scroll>
    )
}

Comment: you didn't use `endTime` as a props of Scroll.
Because you used `<Scroll>endTime={this.state.endTime}`.
I think this was wrong, so that I suggest you to use `<Scroll endTime={this.state.endTime}>`

Answer (score 1):

you didn't use `endTime` as a props of Scroll. Because you used

`<Scroll>
    endTime={this.state.endTime}`.

I think this was wrong, so that Please try to do like this.

```
render() {
    return(
        <Scroll endTime={this.state.endTime}>
            <MessageList
                questions={this.state.questions}
                answers={this.state.answers}
            />
        </Scroll>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The prop end time is on the wrong place. You have to put it inside the scroll component. Try this part of code

```
<Scroll endTime={this.state.endTime}  >
```

Instead of

```
<Scroll> 
           endTime={this.state.endTime}
```